# Why is ellipse blurry at certain scale factor?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

While writing a simple user control I'm currently facing the problem that an ellipse is shown blurry at a certain scale level. Here is a screenshot of the ellipse at two different scale levels.

[image]

I can't figure out what the problem is. The xaml of the user control only consits of an ellipse and a style (whereby the style has to stay like this).

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication8.Ball"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/>
        <Setter Property="OpacityMask" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5, 0.5"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Ellipse>
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Scale}" ScaleY="{Binding Scale}"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>            
</Grid>
```

In the code behind I have two properties. The diameter of the ellipse and the scale value the control binds to.

```
public partial class Ball
{
    public Ball()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private double _diameter;

    public double Diameter
    {
        get { return _diameter; }
        set
        {
            _diameter = value;
            Width = _diameter;
            Height = _diameter;
            Scale = _diameter / 100;
        }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Scale",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(Ball)
    );

    public double Scale
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ScaleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScaleProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Now if I use this control with a diameter of 100 and 70 I get the output show in the screenshot before. I can't figure out why this is happening at a certain scale level. Why is this small ellipse blurry?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <local:Ball Diameter="100"/>
    <local:Ball Diameter="70"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: As a note, setting `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` effectively prevents that the UserControl inherits a DataContext from its parent control. You could e.g. not easily bind its `Scale` property to a view model property. Better remove that line and write the "internal" Scale bindings like `ScaleX="{Binding Scale, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40221481/1136211).

Comment: Try setting SnapToDevicePixels and/or UseLayoutRounding to True. Also ditto re DataContext.

Comment: @Clemens: I get what you are saying, but this is exactly what I want. I don't want the UserControl to inherit a DataContext form a parent control and also I don't want anyone to bind to the Scale property.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Sorry but none of this helped. The problem that is causing this blurry effect is the `OpacityMask`. I used the `OpacityMask` for an animation which isn't show here in the code. I came up with using the opacity of the `Ellipses`'s `Fill` property instead. Now I can scale the control without getting this blurry effect. But still I think it should be investigated why the `OpacityMask` has problems with scaling.

Comment: @Dave Cool -- You should add that as an  answer; someone's bound to run into the same issue.